# String of characters within filename using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to read the below file using the pandas data frame. The letters and numbers after the timestamp changes dynamically. How can i use the Unix property like (filename*) in python?

filename - file_04_23_2018_**5d4da460ab82496a**

```
import pandas as pd
import time
T= time.strftime("%m_%d_%Y")
pd.read_csv("file_{}".format(T))
```

With the code above, I could not read the full name of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may iterate over `glob.glob`:

```
import glob

today = time.strftime("%m_%d_%Y")

df_list = []
for f in glob.glob('file_{}_*'.format(today)):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(f))

df = pd.concat([df_list], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

If it's just one file matching this format, this still works the same, though you may be able to optimise a bit:

```
f = glob.glob('file_{}_*'.format(today))[0]
df = pd.read_csv(f)
```